# C++ two dimensional array in shared memory (based on command line argument)

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to attach a two dimensional (2D) array, existing in a shared memory segment, to a process in C. I get the following error in compilation:

```
main.cpp:52:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int (*)[2]’ [-fpermissive]
  shm_assemble = shmat(shmid_assemble,0,0);
```

and the compile command is:

```
g++ main.cpp -o myworkshop
```

My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "myheader.h"

void perror_exit(char *message);
bool init(int argc, char * argv[], int *Y);

int main (int argc , char* argv[]){

    if(argc<3) {
        perror_exit("Usage: ./myworkshop -Y <value>\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    int i=0,n=0,child_pid=0,Y=0,shmid_paint=0,shmid_assemble=0,shmid_check=0,shmid_y=0,painter_empty=0,painter_full=0,checker_full=0,checker_empty=0,assembler_full=0,assembler_empty=0,ex=0;
    int *pids = new int[8];

    kill_message *shm_y;
    message *shm_paint,*shm_check;
    int (*shm_assemble)[2];

    if (!init(argc,argv,&Y)){
        std::cout << "Something is wrong with the arguments, try again\n";
        exit(-2);
    }

    if(Y==0) return 0; // if no products are to be created the program should exit

    const int SHMSIZE = sizeof(message);                // Shared Memory size = the size of a message
    const int assembler_SHMSIZE = sizeof(int[3*Y][2]);
    printf("assembler_SHMSIZE is: %d\n", assembler_SHMSIZE);
    const int kill_SHMSIZE = sizeof(kill_message);
    // srand(time(NULL));

    /* --- Shared memory creation --- */
    shmid_paint = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    shmid_assemble = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, assembler_SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    shmid_check = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    shmid_y = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, kill_SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    shm_paint = (message*)shmat(shmid_paint,NULL,0);
    shm_assemble = (int **)shmat(shmid_assemble,0,0);
    shm_check = (message*)shmat(shmid_check,NULL,0);
    shm_y = (kill_message*)shmat(shmid
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I read this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764143/creating-a-2d-array-in-the-shared-memory) but I either did not understand the answer correctly or the static size does not help in my case.

My goal is to have a two dimension array of [3*Y][2] integers where Y is given as an argument in main and is initiallized correctly in init function which I did not include here.

Comment: I don't think you need to cast the return value from `shmat`.

Comment: Your code and compiler are C++ (although using some C libraries and idioms). Do you want to do this in C, or do you want to do this in C++?

Comment: The suffix `.cpp` tells the compiler that you have C++ source so it applies C++ rules to that source.  Don't tell it untruths — compilers do not like being lied to and find ways to get their own back when you do.  Yes, they are very different languages, especially in the area of memory management.

Comment: C is C; C++ is C++; C-style C++ is still C++, even though it is using C++ in a particular way. There is *negative* value to confuse it. Don't pretend it is not important, because it is.

Comment: Well, you must be confused about that. I write C++, use C libraries and compile with g++, my file is .cpp but this problem I mention here is not about the language I use so I wrote and tagged C for simplicity. Is it clear now? @AnttiHaapala

Comment: **`int (*shm_assemble)[2] = shmat(shmid_assemble,0,0);`** is legal C. It is not C++, **period**. The reason why your program fails to compile is that you've written a piece of C code in a C++ program. In C++ you need a cast for that. To get help to your *real* problem you need to know to tag the correct programming language.

Comment: No, you are confused. Since your code is C++ and the library is C, it is about interoperation between the two languages. Simplicity never means leaving out important information to confuse people, esp. when you are asking those people for help.

Comment: Can you post an answer, with the proper cast or whatever, for C++? Downvoting and judging/pointing the mistake is not quite helping. The compiler tells me the same! (except from being rude)

Comment: @NickyC Ok, stating C when using C++ was probably a mistake but I cleared that out and I initially thought that It was not a big deal since I've been using C in C++ files for a while without problems for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the answer was quite simple. 
I had to declare shm_write_assembler as int **. My initial int (shm_write_assembler)[2] was working in C, like in the related question I was using as an example but not in C++. Changing this made my code work like a charm.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "myheader.h"

void perror_exit(char *message);
bool init(int argc, char * argv[], int *Y);

int main (int argc , char* argv[]){

    if(argc<3) {
        perror_exit("Usage: ./myworkshop -Y <value>\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    int i=0,n=0,child_pid=0,Y=0,shmid_paint=0,shmid_assemble=0,shmid_check=0,shmid_y=0,painter_empty=0,painter_full=0,checker_full=0,checker_empty=0,assembler_full=0,assembler_empty=0,ex=0;
    int *pids = new int[8];

    kill_message *shm_y;
    message *shm_paint,*shm_check;
    int **shm_assemble;

    if (!init(argc,argv,&Y)){
        std::cout << "Something is wrong with the arguments, try again\n";
        exit(-2);
    }

    if(Y==0) {
        delete[] pids;
        return 0; // if no products are to be created the program should exit
    }

    const int SHMSIZE = sizeof(message);                // Shared Memory size = the size of a message
    const int assembler_SHMSIZE = sizeof(int[3*Y][2]);
    printf("assembler_SHMSIZE is: %d\n", assembler_SHMSIZE);
    const int kill_SHMSIZE = sizeof(kill_message);
    // srand(time(NULL));

    /* --- Shared memory creation --- */
    shmid_paint = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    shmid_assemble = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, assembler_SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    shmid_check = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    shmid_y = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, kill_SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    shm_paint = (message*)shmat(shmid_paint,NULL,0);
    shm_assemble = (int**)shmat(shmid_assemble,NULL,0);
    shm_check = (message*)shmat(shmid_check,NULL,0);
    shm_y = (kill_message*)shmat(shmid_y,NULL,0);

    /* --- Semaphore creation --- */
    painter_empty = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    painter_full = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    checker_empty = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    checker_full = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    assembler_empty = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    assembler_full = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    delete[] pids;
}
```