# problem with matrix in shared memory System V C

Tags: c, matrix, shared-memory

I have a problem using a matrix in a shared memory in C.

I have synthesize the code here:

```
#define MATRIX 1518

int (*matrix)[5], shmMatrix;
shmMatrix = shmget(MATRIX, sizeof(int[5][9]), IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0770);
matrix = shmat(shmMatrix, NULL, 0);

for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) matrix[0][i] = -5;
```

but if i print the matrix in shm, this appears:

```
|       0       -5      -5      -5      -5      -5      -5      -5      -5      |
|       -5      -5      -5      -5      0       0       0       0       0       |
|       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       |
|       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       |
|       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       |
```

for the creation of the matrix in shm, I used [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772046/12683271)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) matrix[0][i] = -5;` <<-- Array indexes start at zero in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I have to change the number of row (5) with the number of columns (9) when I create the array of pointer.

```
(*matrix)[9];
```